# Make Current OpenGL context for SDL 1.2

Tags: c, opengl, sdl

On SDL 2, there is the function `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent`, is there any thing like that for SDL 1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the public API, no.

The [private video backend interface](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/dbaee3350e32/src/video/SDL_sysvideo.h#l182) has a function pointer for it though.

Comment: So, there is not the concept of handling a plural number of contexts on SDL 1.2?

Comment: Correct.  1.2 is also single-window, so I'm not sure what could be done with multiple contexts even if the API was there.